# How to get crash occurred event in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am new to android so don't rate down if you don't like this question. I just want to know the event that triggers when an app crash...

For instance, in which event crashlytics uploads the crash logs to its server....

Comment: You need to give us what happens, otherwise, we can't tell you anything, because we don't have the necessary information. Edit and add more information(post logs, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is a great tool which I use regularly:

https://firebase.google.com

It has all needed tools for analytics and app quality like monitoring your app's performance. If you use Crashlytics.log method, when an app crashes, you can see exactly what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Third party crash reporting tools typically hook up with an [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler) that writes crash data to some persistent local storage and then upload that data when the app is launched again.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to upload the crash remotely... crashlytics or your own UncaughtExceptionHandler.

if you want to monitor a device, connect it to your pc, turn on usb debugging. Open logcat in android studio, should be somewhere in bottom left of your screen (unless u have changed it's place in which case find it yourself). Any crash that happens will show up there